# context menu by left click

Tags: python, pyside2

I am working a a context menu that is triggered by right mouse click over a button. I want it to be triggered by left click.

Comment: If you have "N" problems then you must create "N" posts, please read [ask] and skip the [tour]

Comment: This is such a confusing question mostly because there is no question and only ramblings. Are you just trying to get `B` and `D` to show up in the context menu? Giving context is good, asking a straight question is better.

Comment: @Nachtwache You must respect the rules of SO, the questions in SO must be precise, otherwise your question is off-topic so it could be closed that it is obviously not good.

Comment: @Nachtwache You should be able to ask a new question by now, why does an overly broad question insist on it?

Comment: @Nachtwache Yes, it is a broad question, it is like saying: I want A, B, C, D, E, ..., Z. You know that they are 3 independent problems since you initially separated them. That you want the context menu to be activated with the left click is independent of whether or not there are checkboxes, or whether there are sections. Putting together "n" independent questions is outside the SO rules since the questions here must be precise. Why don't you want to create other questions? Please use `@username`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to detect the left click when pressing the mouse and create a context menu:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            p = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()) # or QtGui.QCursor.pos()
            menu = self.create_menu_contextual()
            action = menu.exec_(p)
            if action is not None:
                print(action.text())

    def create_menu_contextual(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Action1")
        menu.addAction("Action2")
        return menu


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```